# what method gets called when you leave a view to go to another view or to the previous view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

My `UIViewControllers` are pushed inside a `navigationController`.What I want to know is...what method gets called when I go from the current UIViewController to the previous one or forward?

I checked with `viewDidUnLoad` but this doesn't get called.

Any idea?Thank you:)

Comment: Do you want `-(void)viewWillDisappear`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

I recomend you to take an look to the docs [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Class Reference

Answer (score 1):

Check [viewWillAppear](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [viewWillDisappear](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the callbacks suggested in other answers, you can also set a delegate for your UINavigationController and implement the following callbacks

```
– navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
– navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:
```